# Subgroup of an abelian group is a characteristic subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $A \leq N $ where $N$ is abelian, then $A \unlhd N$. But is it true that $A$ char $N$?

Answer (score 3):

No, consider any non-trivial subgroup of the Klein four-group.